# Android 3.x+ + Actionbar + fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I've gone through several posts in stackoverflow but i'm still unable to get the answer to a simple question:

Is it possible to create a fullscreen app in Android 3.x onwards, with the actionbar?

Using the `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

did not do the trick.

Using fullscreen theme, adding the actionbar through code did not do it either.

Does android not allow both to happen at the same time?

Comment: Weird, that same trick makes it work in my app with actionbarsherlock, and also on 4.1 where the native actionbar is used. (However I do set these flags with a handler that has a delay of 1s, after `onResume`)

Comment: Android 3.x is deprecated and now replaced with Android 4.x (except that you still own one tablet with 3.x :))

Comment: I didn't test it on 3.0, only on 4+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on all android versions ( from 4.0 up to 4.2 tested). 
I do use actionbarsherlock, but that uses the native implementation on 4.0+.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getWindow().setFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

What also seems to work is adding it in XML! So that's even better, because it doesn't incurr a show and hiding of the notificationarea. Haven't seen this code anywhere.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.PICK_A_PARENT_THEME_LIKE_ACTIONBAR">         
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

Tested the XML with actionbarsherlock and a freshly created non-actionbarsherlock project.
Both work ok (on 4.0.3). Below is the fresh non-abs app.

[image]

Comment: Did you test that xml theme on non abs? Nevermind, I'll test it right away.

Comment: I tested it without abs, and it does work also! So the xml solution works perfectly to get fullscreen actionbar. See edited answer.

Comment: Or do you mean without the black bottombar? On 3.0 on a tablet you don't have a top bar. So are you referring to that? confused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes nearly.
What worked for me is:
In the Activity in the onCreate method before set Content View:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

and this is in the fragment part, but should also work in an activity:

```
 getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
 getView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

Some devices only dim the navigation buttons. The space of the navigation buttons con not be used, but there are a lot of other View Constants you can use.

kind regards